# Jasmine spyOn does not mock function correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

So I have a function like so:

```
        function initializeView() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var deleteOrUploadToBestMoments = this.deleteOrUploadToBestMoments;
            var checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments = this.checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments;

            getNearbyMoments()
            .then(deleteOrUploadToBestMoments)
            .then(checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments).then(function(moments) {
                //omitted
                }, function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

I wouldl ike to test this function with a unit test.  Here is my test:

```
it('Should call initializeView', function(done) {
    spyOn(service, 'getNearbyMoments').and.callFake(function() {
        console.log("MOCKED getNearbyMoments");
        return $q.resolve(mockOutMoments());
    });
    spyOn(service, 'deleteOrUploadToBestMoments').and.callFake(function() {
        console.log("MOCKED deleteOrUploadToBestMoments");
        return $q.resolve();
    });
    spyOn(service, 'checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments').and.callFake(function() {
        console.log("MOCKED checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments");
        return $q.resolve();
    });
    service.initializeView().then(function(moments) {
        //omitted
        done();
    });
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

The problem is with the spyOn functions.  It is not mocking the correct functions.  However, it does mock it out correctly if I add a 'this' in front of getNearbyMoments in my production code like so:

```
   function initializeView() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var deleteOrUploadToBestMoments = this.deleteOrUploadToBestMoments;
        var checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments = this.checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments;

        this.getNearbyMoments()
        .then(deleteOrUploadToBestMoments)
        .then(checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments).then(function(moments) {
            //omitted
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I could just add a 'this' in front of all my function calls in my production code but this becomes a problem when the context of 'this' changes.  Also, I shouldn't need to change my production code just to make my tests happy - Which makes me really want to figure out what I am doing wrong in my tests so I don't put a band-aid on a potential huge problem.

EDIT:

Apparently I was doing it correctly using 'this'.  But the problem is that whenever I do that I get an error saying

```
'TypeError: this.getNearbyMoments is not a function`
```

Heres my code:

```
function initializeView() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var deleteOrUploadToBestMoments = this.deleteOrUploadToBestMoments;
            var checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments = this.checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments;
            var getNearbyMoments = this.getNearbyMoments;
            this.getNearbyMoments()
            .then(deleteOrUploadToBestMoments)
            .then(checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments).then(function(moments) {
                //omitted
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(error);
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

For some context my service looks something like this:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.momentsService', [])

    .service('momentsService', ['core', '$q', 'constants', 'logger', 'geolocation', 'awsServices', 'localStorageManager', momentsService]);

    function momentsService(core, $q, constants, logger, geolocation, awsService, localStorageManager){

//Lots of other functions
        this.checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments = checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments;
        this.getNearbyMoments = getNearbyMoments;
        this.deleteOrUploadToBestMoments = deleteOrUploadToBestMoments;

        function getNearbyMoments() {
//Omitted...
       };
function initializeView() {
//Well, you already know whats in here...
};
```

So I'm confused because I clearly define the function at the top of the service but for some reason it does not know that it exists.

Comment: Sounds like you may have multiple instances if your service, and you're mocking one while your code is calling another. Can you post full code of your service?

Comment: I perfer to not post my entire service unless I have to.  If I have multiple instances of my service wouldn't it have to do with my jasmine test and not my service itself?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `getNearbyMoments` in a deferred object? Looks like it already returns a promise. This is known as the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Comment: I haven't read your link yet but my thought was I wanted to do things to the object returned by my promise before passing it off to the calling function.  The part of the code that says 'omitted' is possible because of the deferred object.

Answer (score 1):

> `spyOn(service, 'getNearbyMoments').and.callFake(function() {
>           console.log("MOCKED getNearbyMoments");
>           return $q.resolve(mockOutMoments());
>       });`

Due to the mechanics of `spyOn`, it's not possible to modify a call to `getNearbyMoments()`. The reference inside the `initializeView` function cannot be overwritten by `spyOn` in that particular way.

You'll have to add `this` in front of `getNearbyMoments` as you've discovered in order to use `spyOn`.

Otherwise, you can implement the behavior you want by making a publicly exposed reference to `getNearbyMoments` and modifying it. But you'd basically be reimplementing an entire mocking system **and** doing something more complex than adding `this`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a publicly exposed reference.  Are you suggesting that the simplest way is just throwing 'this' in front of my function?  What is the best solution here?

Comment: Yes, add `this`! Your service is well written, this is more of a `spyOn` idiosyncrasy. It will be the easiest and most durable path.

Comment: The problem is if I throw a 'this' in front of getNearbyMoments it says it is 'not a function'

Comment: That's because it needs to be defined as part of the service, with `this.getNearbyMoments =` instead of `var getNearbyMoments =`.

Comment: When I defined the function I did var getNearbyMoments = this.getNearbyMoments;  Isn't that the same thing?  I posted my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show this, but I'm assuming maybe you're doing something like

```
var getNearbyMoments = this.getNearbyMoments;
```

somewhere, since you're trying to spy on `service.getNearbyMoments`, but not actually calling a function by that name that's attached to service. *If* that's the case, my guess is that this is a javascript reference issue. spyOn works something like this (but more complicated):

```
function(obj, method) {
  var originalFn = obj[ method ];
  obj[ method ] = function() {
    // do spy stuff
    // and potentially call the original
    // depending what you do with the spy
    originalFn()
  }
}
```

Because you've assigned the original function to it's own variable, when that function is wrapped by `spyOn`, it no longer points to the same reference.

You either need to use `this` (or `service`) or spy on the function earlier before it's reassigned to a local variable. Again, not seeing more of the code makes this difficult to assess.

For proof of this reference issue, try:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {}
};
var foo = obj.foo;
spyOn(obj, 'foo')
foo();
expect(obj.foo).to.haveBeenCalled() // -> false
```

As for the issue of `this` being different . . . I always define services like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('SomeService', function() {
  var service = {
    foo: function() {
      service.bar();
    },

    bar: function() {
      console.log('bar');
    }
  };
  return service;
});
```

that way everything in the service itself uses a local reference to itself, which never changes.

Comment: Actually there is no 'this.getNearbyMoments' in my production code.  I am trying to spy on getNearbyMoments because I would like to only unit test 'initializeView' and not any of its helper functions.  So ultimately I wouldl ike to mock out getNearbyMoments, deleteOrUploadToBestMoments and checkAndDeleteExpiredMoments functions - I will test those in a separate unit test.  If there is any code that you think I should show please let me know.

Comment: You can't mock a function not attached to an object. It's literally impossible. The signature for `spyOn` is `function(obj, methodName)`. If `getNearbyMoments` is just a local function (e.g. `var getNearbyMoments =`), then you won't be able to spy on it. If it's global (which it shouldn't be), then you could do it with `spyOn(window, 'getNearbyMoments')`.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense.  That would explain why my mocks suddenly started working when I threw 'this' in front of getNearbyMoments.  So would you say using 'this' is the way to go?  Is this more of an issue of how I made my service than anything else?

Comment: Any function you want to mock or test is going to have to be publicly accessible, so I guess it depends on your school of thought with writing tests. I use the pattern in my answer and very rarely use locally scoped functions for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 0):

what about a little that=this?

in the code
        ...
        that=the context
        that.getNearbyMoments()
        .then(deleteOrUploadToBestMoments)

and in the test:

```
...
 that=service
 service.initializeView()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
this.getNearbyMoments()...
```

inside `initializeView()`, you need to change

```
function getNearbyMoments() {
  //Omitted...
};
```

to

```
this.getNearbyMoments = function() {
  //Omitted...
};
```

Comment: Yeah but i also have this.getNearbyMoments = getNearbyMoments; defined as a global variable so that should work